# Stroke or Border color on a btn

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I want to have a stroke on my orange circle, i have tried using a div, and giving it a border with 1px #000000, but i doesn't quite work.

note the circle is perfectly round, it's just jsfiddle that doesn't have font awesome ;)

Here is a jsfiddle of my code.

HTML

```
<div class="button-circle">
   <a href="pages/solutions.html" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
      <i class="fa fa-lock animated"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.btn-circle {
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   padding: 10px 16px;
   border: 3px solid #FC6B0A;
   -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000000;
   border-radius: 100%!important;
   font-size: 40px;
   color: #FC6B0A;
   background: 0 0;
   -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
   transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
   outline: 0;
   border: 3px solid #FC580C;
   color: #FC580C;
   stroke: 1px solid #000000;
   background: rgba(192, 192, 192,.6);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/11gb266r/

**Edit 1**

Okay, I guess i wasn't clear enough. I have my orange Circle inside it is an font awesome lock icon. The lock icon has a text stroke '-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000000;' it gives the icon a 1px wide black stroke. But I want the actual circle to have a 1px black border/stroke too,

Comment: You want to have FA icon with border?

Comment: text-stoke works only on the text. To have a multi-coloured border, you can use, for instance, pseudo-elements with borders of their own.

Comment: By the way, you don't really need FontAwesome to make a round button. Here, an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/11gb266r/6/

Comment: I have updated the question to make my question clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can use inset `text-shadow` to have *stroke* around your icon.

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 #000,
                0 1px #000,
                1px 0 #000,
                0 -1px #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
```